# Android software buttons create a gap in my window/layout

Tags: android, android-layout

When my device is in landscape mode and it sleeps or when I turn off internet, my entire layout and window shifts to the left the exact width of the software buttons.

[My screen with the gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAP11.png)

Seeing this on Android 7.1 and 6.0, both nexus devices with software buttons. Any thoughts on whats causing this and how to fix it or workaround?

Comment: Where is the code, in this case the XML-Lyout files?

Comment: read about `fitSystemWindow` , I think you are doing something wrong with it, (maybe you adding padding in your code?).

https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.328xgcv4x